# How to make nested for loops work faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a DF with a column A containing locations name (i.e. city Xxx, village Yyy, town Zzz) and another DF1 with a column B containing cleaned locations name (without city, village etc.) and columnt C with corresponding state names. I want to match values in DF column A with DF1 column B and if in column copy col B and Col C to DF
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4xCk.png)

I have the next code which works but way too slow:

```
for index in range(len(DF)):
    for name in range(len(DF1)):
        if data1.loc[name, 'B'] in data.loc[index, 'A']:
            data.loc[index, 'B'] = data1.loc[name, 'B']
            data.loc[index, 'C'] = data1.loc[name, 'C']
```

Is there any way to make this faster?

Comment: This seems like a job for [.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) but I'm still thinking about how to apply it.

Comment: Please provide you input/output datasets as dataframe constructors, not image. Images are not reproducible and ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better solution than what I posted previously. It should also require way less memory.

```
df[['B','C']] = df1['B'].apply(lambda x: df1[['B','C']].loc[df['A'].str.contains(x)].iloc[0])
```

Note: if DF1 only has two columns, you can remove that [['B', 'C']] inside the lambda function since it isn't necessary.

Also, if you only need the location name without the word(s) before it (town, city, etc.) you can update A with B's values, without creating another unnecessary column:

```
df[['A','C']] = df1['B'].apply(lambda x: df1[['B','C']].loc[df['A'].str.contains(x)].iloc[0])
```

Comment: got this "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.55 GiB for an array with shape (3, 69343274) and data type float64". Both DF are quite big 24k and 3k rows, 22 and 15 columns

Comment: @AntonBagaev Do your values in DF["A"] always contain only one word (e.g. town, city, village, etc.) before the actual location name? If not, do you actually need that part?

Comment: No, not always it can be one, two and three words followed by one or two words of a place name. And I need only a place name

Comment: @AntonBagaev I edited my answer and included a better solution. Let me know if it works (:

Comment: got the error "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

Comment: I think this happens when value in df1["B"] is not found in df['A']

Answer (score -1):

You could just split DF into multiple sections and use multiprocessing or multithreading for each section to run the processes simultaneously. This [link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/multiprocessing-for-data-scientists-in-python-427b2ff93af1) might be useful.